# C++ - ponteiro this

Tags: c++, this

As funções RotateX(float) e Scale(float, float, float) da classe mat4 retorna o ponteiro this. O propósito era criar uma instancia temporária de mat4 para armazenar a pré-multiplicação entre as funções Scale e Rotate. Do seguinte modo:

```
mat4 mat4::RotateX(float theta){
    matrix[1][1] = cos(DegToRad(theta));
    matrix[2][1] = sin(DegToRad(theta));
    matrix[1][2] = -sin(DegToRad(theta));
    matrix[2][2] = cos(DegToRad(theta));
    return *this;
}
mat4 mat4::Scale(float x, float y, float z){
    matrix[0][0] = x;
    matrix[1][1] = y;
    matrix[2][2] = z;
    return *this;
}
```

```
    mat4 transform;
    mat4 temp;
       
    transform = temp.RotateX(theta) * temp.Scale(x, y, z);
```

Tem-se o seguinte atributo da classe:

```
float matrix[4][4]
```

A classe mat4 possui uma sobrecarga do operador de multiplicação (*) o qual realiza uma operação de multiplicação de matrizes.

```
mat4 mat4::operator*(const mat4& m) const{
    mat4 mult;
    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for(uint8_t j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            mult[i][j] = matrix[i][0] * m[0][j] 
                       + matrix[i][1] * m[1][j] 
                       + matrix[i][2] * m[2][j] 
                       + matrix[i][3] * m[3][j];
        }
    }
    return mult;
}
```

Assim, temp é resultado da concatenação entre uma operação de escala e rotação.

Tal como está, essa estrutura viabiliza fazer isso:

```
transform.Scale(x, y, z);
```

Isso é legal para a linguagem considerando que Scale() retorna o ponteiro this, que por sua vez armazena o endereço da instância que chama a função? Isso seria o mesmo que realizar uma copia de objetos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Assim, temp é resultado da concatenação entre uma operação de escala e rotação.

Isso me parece bem confuso e está criando uma cópia desnecessária pois o que você está retornando em cada um desses métodos não é um ponteiro, e sim um objeto `mat4`. Para evitar a cópia você deve retornar por referência (basta mudar o tipo de retorno de `mat4` para `mat4&`.

Mas mesmo que você mude para referência e o código faça o que você quer, ainda acredito não ser uma boa nesse caso.

Ao ver um método chamado `RotateX` e outro chamado `Scale` o que me vem na cabeça como o natural é que eles modificam o objeto atual, mas no seu caso eles estão funcionando mais como inicializadores de um novo objeto (eles não usam nada do estado atual do objeto). Acho que, considerando o que esses dois métodos atualmente fazem, eles poderiam ser modificados para serem "métodos estáticos de fábrica". Ou seja, métodos estáticos que você usa para **criar um novo objeto**. Com isso a linha

```cpp
transform = temp.RotateX(theta) * temp.Scale(x, y, z);
```

viraria

```cpp
transform = mat4::RotateX(theta) * mat4::Scale(x, y, z);
```

Além disso, os nomes podem ser mais sugestivos. Algo como trocar `RotateX`, que dá a impressão que vai rotacionar a matriz atual de alguma forma, para algo como `fromRotationX` e `Scale` para algo como `fromDiagonal` (já que o que você está fazendo é criar uma matriz diagonal e nada tem a ver com escalar uma matriz). Assim a linha inicializando `transform` ficaria

```cpp
transform = mat4::fromRotationX(theta) * mat4::fromDiagonal(x, y, z);
```

O fato de você está usando métodos estáticos na linha acima deixa claro que você está criando dois novos objetos que serão multiplicados para obter `transform` e os nomes deixam mais claro de que modo esses objetos são criados. Como agora eles são métodos estáticos, então o tipo de retorno é apenas `mat4`. Uma implementação para `fromDiagonal` poderia ser como abaixo

```cpp
// Coloque static no .h
static mat4 mat4::fromDiagonal(float x, float y, float z){
    mat4 result;
    result.matrix[0][0] = x;
    result.matrix[1][1] = y;
    result.matrix[2][2] = z;
    return result;
}
```

---

Um detalhe interessante é que o compilador é inteligente e mesmo retornando  um `mat4` ele pode evitar cópia nos casos mais comuns quando você usar esse método estático. Se fizer algo como

```cpp
mat4 umaMatrizDiagonal = mat4::fromDiagonal(x, y, z);
```

o compilador vai ver o valor de retorno de `fromDiagonal` é atribuído a uma variável e quando ele criar `result` dentro de `fromDiagonal` ele já cria no local onde `umaMatrizDiagonal` está, evitando assim a cópia.

Comment: Uma pequena observação para função fromDiagonal, em mat4.matrix o correto deveria ser result.matrix?

Comment: Sim, você está certo. Corrigido.

Answer (score 0):

Sim, caso queira retornar o próprio objeto você altera o protótipo para retornar uma referência.

Trocando:

```
 mat4 mat4::Scale(float x, float y, float z)
```

por:

```
 mat4& mat4::Scale(float x, float y, float z)
```